# Why would Google Earth be hanging for 5-10 seconds?

Tags: google-earth

Google Earth has always worked well for me, but lately it **hangs for about 10 seconds** when I click on one of the pictures. It even says in the application bar "**(Not Responding)**" and then returns. This also happens if I click on a link inside google earth such as for a hotel which brings up a website inside google earth, it hangs for about 10 seconds and then brings up the site.

It also happens when I click on a Street View icon.

It seems to happen any time Google earth has to go fetch something.

**Does anyone know how I get Google Earth to stop hanging like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what would cause it, but the first things I would try are a repair, and then if that doesn't work try to do a re-install.

Comment: I had installed it with http://www.ninite.com. I uninstalled it then reinstalled it but chose 5.1 instead of 5.2 and unchecked all the "notify google about personal usage". Now it works. Don't know which of those three factors it was but at least its lightning fast now, thanks for the reinstall idea.